# ReactJS: React CountUp visible only once in visibility sensor

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-animations

I am working on a page that has a [visibility sensor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-visibility-sensor) so that whenever I scroll to that section, the animation starts. However, I only need it to be visible only once.

```
const [scrollStatus, setScroll] = useState(false);
    const contextData = {
        stateSetters: {
            scrollStatus
        }

    }
```

```
<ScrollContext.Provider value={contextData}>
    <VisibilitySensor onChange={() => {
       setScroll(!scrollStatus);
    }}>
    <CountUp start={0} end={scrollStatus ? 0 : 40} duration={1.75} suffix="+"/>
    </VisibilitySensor>
</ScrollContext.Provider>
```

I am currently using hooks and functional components. I have been looking for ways to be able to set the visibility to true once it has been viewed.

The output should become already visible and not visible only every scroll.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by dee zg, you can set the status of the `VisibilitySensor` by using the event attribute [isVisible](https://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor#example) and the property [active](https://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor#props), as roughly shown in the following example.

A small running code example can be found on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-paper-1i4vu?file=/src/VisSensor_status_active.js).

```js
import React from "react";
import VisibilitySensor from "react-visibility-sensor";

class myTest extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            VizSensorActive: true
        };

        this.do_something = this.do_something.bind(this);
    }

    do_something(isVisible) {
        if (isVisible) {
            this.setState({ VizSensorActive: false });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <VisibilitySensor
                active={this.VizSensorActive}
                onChange={this.do_something}
            >
                <div>Test</div>
            </VisibilitySensor>
        );
    }
}

export default myTest;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don’t want to toggle state unconditionally but rather just set it to `true` once your visibility sensor calls its `onChange` callback with `isVisible=true`

So, something like this (i havent tested it):

```
function handleVisibility(isVisible) {
!scrollStatus &&
isVisible &&
setScroll(isVisible);
}

<VisibilitySensor onChange={handleVisibility}>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy example of using react-countup and react-visibility-sensor for viewing the effect for once only

```
import React from "react";
import CountUp from "react-countup";
import VisibilitySensor from "react-visibility-sensor";

function Milestones() {
    const [focus, setFocus] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <CountUp start={focus ? 0 : null} end={150} duration={4} redraw={true}>
            {({ countUpRef }) => (
                <VisibilitySensor onChange={(isVisible) => {
                    if (isVisible) { setFocus(true); }
                }}>
                    <span ref={countUpRef} />
                </VisibilitySensor>
            )}
        </CountUp>
    )
}

export default Milestones;
```