# Animation from react-spring fires off too fast with visibility-sensor and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-spring

I have wrapper React Component which makes its children fade in from right side and change opacity from 0 to 1, using react-spring and visibility-sensor.
Both useEffect and useState make the chidren appear only once after first scroll in.

The problem is that animation shows too fast - there is no transform from 50px from right side to end position. Image/text - the component children just pop up as i scroll in.

Here is the code for this Component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Spring, config } from 'react-spring/renderprops';
import VisibilitySensor from 'react-visibility-sensor';

export const FadeInContainer = ({
 children
}: any) => {
 const [isVisible, setVisibility] = useState(false);
 const [entered, setEntered] = useState(false);

 const onChange = (visiblity: any) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   setVisibility(visiblity);
  }, 200);
 };

 useEffect(() => {
  if (isVisible) {
   setEntered(true);
  }
 }, [isVisible]);

 const FadeInDirection = () => {
  return (
   <Spring
    delay={500}
    config={config.slow}
    to={{
     opacity: entered ? 1 : 0,
     transform: entered ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(50px)'
    }}
   >
    {({ opacity, transform }) => (
     <div style={{ opacity, transform }}>{children}</div>
    )}
   </Spring>
  );
 };

 return (
  <VisibilitySensor onChange={onChange}>
   <FadeInDirection />
  </VisibilitySensor>
 );
};
```

What I've tried already: 
1. Adding setTimeouts to useEffect, and onChange definition as above.
2. Tried adding scrollDelay for visibility sensor as below:

```
  <VisibilitySensor onChange={onChange} scrollDelay={300}>
```

The solution for scrolling only once is from this thread: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58488868

Do you know if something can be done to make animation which happens only once on scroll more smooth (transform mostly)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that the animation is not working. It just switches opacity from 0 to 1 without animation. I changed it to the hook based animation and it just worked (only when useSpring was outside the `FadeInDirection` component). 
So the initial problem is, that `FadeInDirection` defined inside `FadeInContainer` and it has no properties of its own. It was redefined with each render.

Create `FadeInDirection` as a separate component.

I also eliminated the useEffect, I only set visible when `VisibilitySensor` onChange return true.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";
import VisibilitySensor from "react-visibility-sensor";

const FadeInDirection = ({ isVisible, children }) => {
  const props = useSpring({
    opacity: isVisible ? 1 : 0,
    transform: isVisible ? "translateY(0px)" : "translateY(50px)"
  });
  return <animated.div style={props}>{children}</animated.div>;
};

export const FadeInContainer = ({ children }) => {
  const [isVisible, setVisibility] = useState(false);

  const onChange = visiblity => {
    visiblity && setVisibility(visiblity);
  };

  return (
    <VisibilitySensor onChange={onChange}>
      <FadeInDirection isVisible={isVisible}>{children}</FadeInDirection>
    </VisibilitySensor>
  );
};
```

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-sun-oqv0v?file=/src/App.js:184-787